# Is there any way to check the prize process of Windows 8 Challenge?

Tags: support, windows-8-challenge

I got an email from Stack Overflow employee regarding Windows 8 Challenge Winner level 1, the image is as follows,

[image: prizes email]

I filled the details and submitted about a week ago. Basically i am from india, so it would obviously take time to reach my prize.

Is there any mechanism to check what is the progress of the Windows's prize distribution?  Even there was no response email which says that I have filled my detail or not. I think an automated email needed to fire after submitting the details that "Thank you for filling your submission details, You will get your prize soon"

Comment: Just FYI, I received my level 2 price in the mail on Monday 19th (dispatched from Amazon UK). No level 1 shirt yet though.

Comment: Nice, Congratulations, Now i have some relief that i will get my t-shirt may be by next week :)

Comment: Not Yet, I think may be next week

Comment: @Karan, not yet, i am still waiting, may be one more week to go or by this weekend.

Comment: Just to note I got my shirt so they should be reaching people sooner rather than later.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, good, for your information, my question is not about the doubting for prize, I just wanted to have a facility for tracking the prize reaching process to your home. Mine T-Shirt is also on the way.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, i just got my t-shirt as well :) , Thanks to Stack Exchange Team

Answer (score 0):

The prizes are generally shipped via [USPS](https://www.usps.com/) - so other than having to sit tight & wait, there's no way to check the prize process.

Comment: ok agree but atleast SO should sent me an email(auto generated) regarding i filled my submission detail, shouldn't it ?

Comment: you get a notification once you submit the form. Email would be nice, but I don't see how it'll be useful

Comment: agree but notification was temporary, while an email is really a better option. I am just doubting whether you got my details or not ?

Comment: There is a tracking process in that site, so if S.O. provide me my receipt number in returned email than i can easily track it :)

Comment: If users want to email me (brett at stack exchange dot com) to verify that their info was received, I can do that. Unfortunately there is no automation in place and won't be put in place for this contest, so that's the best we can do right now. Sorry for any inconvenience that causes!